# When using AES-NI as a high-speed permutation, does AESDEC offer better diffusion?

Tags: aes, pseudo-random-permutation, diffusion

If I was to use AES-NI as a high performance 128-bit permutation/PRF would AESDEC offer faster/better diffusion than AESENC? The reason I ask is because both instructions have the same cost, but the inverse MixColums step of AES has a more complicated matrix, so it appears to me as if there are more operations being performed for the same cost.

Comment: Does what you're making need to be cryptographically secure?

Comment: @Myria No, I am mostly interested in non-cryptographic RNGs at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, `AESDEC` is probably better for this purpose; its results will "look" more random.  You might want to also consider adding `CRC32` for more fun.

Comment: AES with a fixed key is just a permutation ( AES is not PRF it is PRP), so the enc dec is just the reverse of each other. No difference.

Comment: @kelalaka I am fully aware that the two operations are inverse of each other, but that doesn't convince me that one doesn't scramble bits faster than the other. For instance, I took the MixColums and the inverse MixColums functions, and I put every 32-bit integer which is a power of 2 through them and then summed the hamming weights. The result was that Inverse MixColums produced almost twice as many 1s as the normal MixColums.

Comment: OK, instead of just testing MixColums by itself, I decided to test the whole AESENC and AESDEC and it seem like once you throw SubBytes in there, AESENC actually ends up having a higher hamming weight than AESDEC.

Comment: Sorry, but are you stating that the permutation offered by AES is not randomized by they key value? How did you test that, how much data and how many keys? Because if the AES key doesn't randomly select a permutation then some block cipher modes such as CTR mode can not be IND-CPA secure, imho. I can imagine one of these functions being faster, but I cannot see how one of these functions would select a permuation "more randomly".

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I used an all zero key, since the key is only XORed into the block. I wanted to get a sense for how much the SubBytes/MixColums steps mix things up all on their own.